# Using enable_if to decide the type of a member variable

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++17, variadic-templates, variant

```cpp
template <typename ...T>
class BaseEvent
{
    BaseEvent(const unsigned int index, const uint8_t id, const std::variant<T...> data) : m_index(index), m_id(id), m_data(m_data){};
    virtual ~BaseEvent();

    template <typename V>
    const V get()
    {
        static_assert(constexpr std::is_same_v<V, T...>);
        return std::get<V>(m_data);
    };

protected:
    unsigned int m_index;
    uint8_t m_id;
    std::variant<T...> m_data;
    
    // pseudocode:
    // enable_if(sizeof(T...) > 1)
    // then: std::variant<T...> m_data
    // else: T m_data
};
```

However later in the code,

```cpp
template <class T>
class StringEvent : public BaseEvent<T>
{
    virtual ~StringEvent();
    const T string() { return get<T>(); };
};
```

Pasing only a single type to `BaseEvent` will not be able to create `variant` as it is useless in that case anyways. **How can I use `enable_if` to create `m_data` of type `T` when `T...` is a single type only?**

Comment: What's the problem of having a case of `std::variant<T>`? https://godbolt.org/z/o33MjaEh7

Comment: Interfaces are easier to use, whether generically or directly, when they are regular. Don't needlessly break the pattern.

Comment: @rturrado Well it does work but what is the use of variant with single type?

Comment: @Deduplicator I didn't get you. Are you saying I should keep it how it is now?

Comment: `virtual BaseEvent(...)` - what flavour of C++ are you using? I only know one that has `virtual` constructors. That variadic amount of return types in `const T... get()` is however nothing I've seen anywhere.

Comment: @TedLyngmo is it ok now?

Comment: @demberto Deduplicator gave you the key to that question: genericity. What could you think of better than a code that works regardless of how many types the `variant` has to deal with?

Comment: @demberto What do you mean _"is it ok now?_"? I take it that you copy/paste your code as it is, so if you have `virtual` constructors, you do. I only asked what flavour of C++ you are using. Edit: I noticed that you also changed to `const T... get()` to `const V get()` so, I get the feeling that you are not actually showing us real code. Show us what you've really got so we don't have to guess.

Comment: There is no problem that cannot be solved with an extra layer of abstraction, except having too many layers of abstraction.

Comment: @TedLyngmo My bad, I am new to templates entirely, so I depend on error messages from the IDE in case something goes wrong. I opened this is VS and I get a lot of error messages, I have fixed the code and all this code is real *except I have omitted some member functions for keeping it short*

Comment: If you have something that is either `T` or `std::variant<Ts...>`, then whenever you use it, you will also have to have a condition on `sizeof...(Ts)`, whereas if you have `std::variant<T>`, you `std::visit` everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done exactly what you want to do, so I know what you need. To handle both single message and multiple message types, use `std::variant<std::monostate, T...>`. In addition, your use of `is_same_v<>` is incorrect. You can only use 1 type, not multiple types there.

So you need a code like this:

```
template <typename ...T>
class BaseEvent
{
    BaseEvent(const unsigned int index, const uint8_t id, const std::variant<T...> data) : m_index(index), m_id(id), m_data(m_data){}; 
    // ^-- There is a small bug here in creating variant(different types). you need to solve, and use in-place for variant.
    virtual ~BaseEvent();

    template <typename V>
    const V get()
    {
        static_assert(is_valid_type<V>() || std::is_same_v<V, std::monostate>);
        return std::get<V>(m_data);
    };

protected:
    unsigned int m_index;
    uint8_t m_id;
    std::variant<std::monostate, T...> m_data;

private:
    template<typename U>
    constexpr static bool is_valid_type() {
        return (std::is_same_v<U, T> || ...);
    }    
};
```

My main code is much more complex and I just extracted small part for this, so use it with care.

Comment: `monostate` has quite a few uses, and thanks for pointing out the incorrect use of `is_same_v`

Comment: @demberto I have a full queue for handling event using variant, So I know exactly what you want to do. :) I have event compared it with a polymorphic version and it was around 10% better in performance, but just remember to take care of a lot of details. For example, remember to user `in-place` initialization for your variant.

Comment: You mean use `const std::variant<std::in_place_t, std::monostate, const T...> data`?

Comment: @demberto yes, but it is trickier than it seems.